# Lua get/set functions for specific keys only

Tags: lua

I have a table populated with functions, variables and constants.

What is the proper way of adding get/set functions for a specific key or keys?

For example when I read "b" I want to execute some functon getb() and when I write to "b" I want to execute some function setb(). What I want to do and also what I've tried and failed is portrayed on the code snippet below.

```
t = {
    a = function ()
        print("doa")
    end,
    
    c = function ()
        print("doc")
    end
}

_b = 0

function getb()
    return _b
end

function setb(v)
    _b = v
end

mt = {
  __index = function (t,k)
    if (k == "b") then return getb() end -- call custom get functions for one or more specific keys
    return t[k]   -- access the original table
  end,

  __newindex = function (t,k,v)
    if (k == "b") then setb(v)  -- call custom set functions for one or more specific keys
    else t[k] = v end -- access the original table
  end
}
setmetatable(t, mt)

t.a()
t.b = 3
print(t.b)
t.c()
t.d = 3 -- this line causes infinite recursion
print(t.d) -- this line causes infinite recursion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is very simple: You're not using `rawget` or `rawset`. Specifically, in your `__index` metamethod, you `return t[k]` as a default. This invokes the `__index` metamethod again though! In the same vein, `t[k] = v` in `__newindex` is a hidden recursive call to `__newindex`.

The fix is trivial: Just replace `return t[k]` in `__index` with `return rawget(t, k)` and `t[k] = v` in `__newindex` with `rawset(t, k, v)`.

Note that changing or accessing a field after it has been set then won't trigger an `__index` or `__newindex` event, so if you do `t.d = 1; t.d = 2; print(t.d)`, only the first assignment will trigger `__newindex`; the second assignment and the indexing operation won't trigger `__newindex`.

Alternatively, you could leave `t` without a metatable, and instead create a new proxy table. This would allow preserving `t`'s metatable behavior if it has any at the cost of requiring one hash lookup miss and metamethod invocation for each access.

```lua
local proxy = setmetatable({}, mt)

proxy.a() -- gets t.a
proxy.b = 3
print(proxy.b)
proxy.c() -- gets t.c
proxy.d = 3 -- sets t.d
print(proxy.d) -- gets t.d
```

The advantage of using a proxy table is that **all** indexing operations have to pass through it, since your proxy table is empty at all times.

It is not uncommon to use actual getters and setters in Lua though. It may make using a table slightly less convenient, but it makes function calls explicit, thus preventing issues such as this infinite recursion issue. It is also more convenient for the implementor (vs. metatables).

Comment: By: "actual getters and setters" you mean creating explicit get() and set() functions and not some specific Lua language construct?

Comment: @user1806687 yes, often "methods" like `obj:setX(val)` (which may again be looked up over a metatable)